# Upload file via multipart request

Tags: http, d

I need to upload a zip file to a url that accepts files passed in a multipart request. The name of the part in the "multipart/form-data" request to bind to is "archive".

What I have so far:

```
        auto f = new BufferedFile(<path_to_file>, FileMode.In);
        scope (exit) f.close();

        http = HTTP(<post_url>);
        http.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=heregoes");
        http.verifyPeer(false);
        http.method = HTTP.Method.post;
        http.onSend = (void[] data){
            return f.read(cast(ubyte[]) data);
        };
        http.contentLength = cast(size_t) f.size;
        http.setCookieJar("<cookie_file_used_for_auth>");
        http.perform();
```

How can I set the key "archive" in the request to map the file to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use std.net.curl much so I don't know if there's an easier way, but the data you're sending is just a blob on the wire, so you could set the other values manually.

Don't just send the data, put it in a MIME envelope. I wrote this little class a while ago to help form that:

```
/// Creates a multipart/form-data object that is suitable for file uploads and other kinds of POST
class FormData {
    struct MimePart {
        string name;
        const(void)[] data;
        string contentType;
        string filename;
    }

    MimePart[] parts;

    void append(string key, in void[] value, string contentType = null, string filename = null) {
        parts ~= MimePart(key, value, contentType, filename);
    }

    private string boundary = "0016e64be86203dd36047610926a"; // FIXME

    ubyte[] toBytes() {
        string data;

        foreach(part; parts) {
            data ~= "--" ~ boundary ~ "\r\n";
            data ~= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""~part.name~"\"";
            if(part.filename !is null)
                data ~= "; filename=\""~part.filename~"\"";
            data ~= "\r\n";
            if(part.contentType !is null)
                data ~= "Content-Type: " ~ part.contentType ~ "\r\n";
            data ~= "\r\n";

            data ~= cast(string) part.data;

            data ~= "\r\n";
        }

        data ~= "--" ~ boundary ~ "--\r\n";

        return cast(ubyte[]) data;
    }
}
```

I know that code sucks and I haven't tested it recently but the output eyeballs to be right. It should work like this:

```
auto data = new FormData();
data.append("archive", "YOUR DATA", "application/octet-stream"); // or whatever mime type you need

auto bytes = data.toBytes();
```

Then you send bytes instead of your file contents when curl asks for it. The `setPostData` method of `HTTP` looks like a place to put it. Remember to set your content type in the set post data too to the multipart/form-data with the boundary (you can change the one in my class if you like).

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html#setPostData

I know the curl library has functions to do this for you too... but I don't think the high level std.net.curl interface exposes them :(

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I did however have to modify it a little here:  "data ~= "Content-Disposition: form-data," -> "data ~= "Content-Disposition: form-data;".

Comment: cool, fixed. Did it otherwise work out? I wish there was an easier way but if it works we at least have some kind of solution here!